# Is it possible to make Gmail check my imported account more frequently?

Tags: gmail

I imported some of my email accounts in my Gmail, and now I’m receiving and sending only from Gmail.

The only problem is that some times it takes about 45 minutes to know that I received a new email on these external accounts, because Gmail checks for new emails every 45 minutes I think.

Is there any way to force Gmail checking one of these accounts more frequently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Lifehacker on [Make Gmail Check Your POP Accounts More Frequently](http://lifehacker.com/5346103/make-gmail-check-your-pop-accounts-more-frequentlyBlockquote)

> The solution, then? **Your account needs to get more email.** Naturally, though, you don't want to flood your Gmail inbox with new email just so you can be sure your POP account is checking at more reasonable intervals. The post suggests setting up some Terminal scripts with Automator to send your POP account emails on a regular basis, then filtering out those emails when they hit Gmail so you never have to deal with them.
>
> If you're not on OS X or you don't love the Automator idea, you could probably offload the frequent emailing duties to some other web service. An active Google Group seems like a good option; you could sign up for the group, set the Google Group to send emails for all new posts, and then just filter the Google Group email out when it hits your Gmail inbox (via the POP inbox).

Comment: sorry, can't understand what should i do :(

Comment: @Amr you basically have to receive more mail in that account. By default it checks the POP accounts every 1hour, unless there is more traffic. So the suggestion here is to subscribe to an active google group and start receiving mails for every new post and then simply filter out these mails (like sending them to trash)

Comment: Ah, got you, fine thanks :), nice trick